# Debian's corresponding command for add-apt-repository?

Tags: debian, software-installation, backup

I want to run this in Debian 8.1

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:nemh/systemback
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install systemback
```

but I cannot find `add-apt-repository` in Debian 8.1 and its `apt-file search`/`apt-cache search`.

Is Debian's way of changing the source just editing the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `add-apt-repository` command is part of the `software-properties-common` package in Debian 8.x (jessie). Once you've installed `software-properties-common`, you'll have `add-apt-repository` available and you can use it to add PPA repositories.

**Note:** Be sure that the packages you're installing are compatible with Debian. If the packages are only available for Ubuntu and you need to install the package that is the "best match" to your Debian release, you'll need to adjust the appropriate repository entry, for example to change the release from `jessie` to `utopic` or `vivid` (by default, the repository will be added with the release name that matches your Debian release, as you'd expect).

For example

From:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nemh/systemback/ubuntu jessie main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nemh/systemback/ubuntu jessie main
```

To:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nemh/systemback/ubuntu vivid main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nemh/systemback/ubuntu vivid main
```

Comment: I have Debian Jessie i.e. 8.1 so the first two lines should work. That is a good point! Do you know what this command `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:nemh/systemback` inserts by default? For Jessie or Vivid?

Comment: @Masi The problem is that the package probably isn't available for jessie, so you'll need to install the package from the closest match Ubuntu release (possibly vivid). To do that, you need to change the repository entry.

Comment: Is this `ppa:nemh/systemback` available in Jessie? How did you look it up? It is better to use just supported software for me.

Comment: @Masi There doesn't appear to be a package for Debian, only Ubuntu. See the [package page](https://launchpad.net/~nemh/+archive/ubuntu/systemback) on Launchpad. Yes, ideally you shouldn't install Ubuntu packages on a Debian system. What you can do is rebuild the Ubuntu package on a Debian system and then install that package - your dependencies will then be 100% correct. The [backporting](https://wiki.debian.org/SimpleBackportCreation) instructions should be a good starting point.

Comment: The first link does not work after additing those lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and running `apt-get update` getting *W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nemh/systemback/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found; W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nemh/systemback/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found*. Of course, like you said, I should use Vivid's ones but do not like so the software is not supported in my debian.

Comment: @Masi Yes, hence my comment that you'd need to change **jessie** to the name of the "best match" Ubuntu distribution. There is no package for jessie on that repository.